# Incorrect count value in subquery on table join column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The query I'm executing seems to be ignoring the where clause in the subquery
(select count(amazon) from orders where b.amazon = 2 and manifest = a.dbid)

column amazon is type INT
SQL SERVER 2014

If I run the query on its own and enter the value for manifest I get the correct result which I am expecting and is 1

select count(amazon) from orders where amazon = 2 and manifest = '211104'
Result Returns 1

When I run the query below I get a result of 5 which is the count of all orders where manifest = 211104 but the value of amazon is 1 in 4 results and 2 in 1 result.

```
Select  distinct
top 30 DBID, today ,sum([amazon-orders])
From
(
    SELECT [dbid], [today], 
        (select count(amazon) from orders 
         where b.amazon = 2 and manifest = a.dbid) as [amazon-orders]
    FROM [manifest] a
    join orders b on a.[dbid] = b.[manifest]
) t1  
Group By 
DBID, today
order by dbid desc
```

[image: SQL SELECT]
[image: SQL RESULTS]

Can someone please help me.

Thanks

Comment: "When I run the query below I get a result of 5 which is the count of all orders where manifest = 211104 but the value of amazon is 1 in 4 results and 2 in 1 result" What result are you expecting for 211104?

Comment: see the top result in the image shows a count of 5 for DBID 211104, this is a count of all orders but I am only trying to get the count of orders where column amazon = 2 and the result for this is 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How's this?

```
SELECT top 30 [dbid], [today], sum(case when b.amazon = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as [amazon-orders]
FROM [manifest] a
join orders b on a.[dbid] = b.[manifest]
group by DBID, today
order by dbid desc
```

Pretty sure that because your query is in effect joining orders twice it's increasing the count.

Comment: Indeed, but with no test data, who knows? Cross/Outer Apply could also work.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra join so you are counting multiple times... do this:

```
Select  distinct
top 30 DBID, today ,sum([amazon-orders])
From
(
    SELECT [dbid], [today], 
        (select count(amazon) from orders b
         where b.amazon = 2 and manifest = a.dbid) as [amazon-orders]
    FROM [manifest] a
) t1  
Group By 
DBID, today
order by dbid desc
```

or like this

```
SELECT [dbid], [today], count(o.amazon)
FROM [manifest] a
join orders o on a.dbid = o.manifest and o.amazon = 2
group by dbid, today
```

or this if you have columns you don't want to join (there is more going on than just this one join in your query and you need to use a left join):

```
SELECT [dbid], [today], sum(case when o.amazon is not null then 1 else 0 end)
FROM [manifest] a
left join orders o on a.dbid = o.manifest and o.amazon = 2
group by dbid, today
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the answer from Gareth Lyons solved my problem. Yours gives me The multi-part identifier "b.amazon" could not be bound.
Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: @jasonkkt -- I fixed that you needed a "b" after the table name.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
select  a.DBID, a.today, count(b.amazon) from [manifest] a
join orders b on a.[dbid] = b.[manifest] and b.amazon = 2
Group By a.DBID, a.today
```

Comment: @jasonkkt - just wondering if this query works for you or not ?